# RFID-RC522 can't read all tags raspberry

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, rfid

I installed my RC-522 with raspberry pi zero wh it works fine, it reads the cards that came with the device, but it cannot read other cards that operate on the same frequency which is 13.56 MHz
that's my read.by code.

```
def uidToString(uid):
mystring = ""
for i in uid:
mystring = format(i, '02X') + mystring
return mystring
def end_read(signal, frame):
global continue_reading
print("Ctrl+C captured, ending read.")
continue_reading = False
GPIO.cleanup()

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, end_read)

MIFAREReader = MFRC522.MFRC522()

print("MFRC522 data read ")
print("Press Ctrl-C to stop.")

while continue_reading:

(status, TagType) = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Request(MIFAREReader.PICC_REQIDL)

if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:
    print ("Card detected")

    (status, uid) = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_SelectTagSN()
    if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:
        print("Card read UID: %s" % uidToString(uid))
        
        
    else:
```

Comment: Can you complete with the end of your code?

Comment: What types of cards do you try to read? Are they MIFARE classic?